# Python nested loops only working on the first pass

Tags: python, arrays, loops

**Objective**:
Write a screen-scraper that will check web pages to see if they contain certain contents.

**Method**:
Have two config files, one containing a list of URLs, and another containing a list of strings to search for. Open both files and read in their contents as two arrays.

Loop through the array of URLs (let's call it Loop A).

For each URL, read in the page using urllib and split it up into an array by splitting on the \n. Loop through the list of strings (Loop B).

For each line in the strings, loop through the lines of HTML (Loop C), and on each line do a pattern match. Record the results in an output file if a match is found.

**Problem**:
It's opening the config files okay.
Loop A is working fine. Loops B and C are only working on the first pass of Loop A. On the second and third passes of Loop A, Loop B is not happening.

Forgive me for putting in so much debugging code. One curious quirk is that I'm seeing a mysterious 'b' appearing in my output produced by line 52 of the code.

**Config file contents**:

urls.txt

```
http://uk.norton.com
http://us.norton.com
http://ie.norton.com
```

targetStrings.txt

```
Norton Online Backup
Norton Ultimate Help Desk
```

**Code**:

```
# Import the modules we need
import urllib.request
import re

# Open the files we need
out = open('out.txt', 'w')
urls=open('urls.txt','r')
targetFile=open('targetStrings.txt','r',encoding=('utf-8'))

# function to take a URL, open the HTML, split it into an array, and return it
def getPage(url):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode().split('\n')

# function to kick out to an output file
def outFile(output):
    out.write(output + '\n')

# Function to test for matches    
def match(string, pageLine):
    if re.search(string.encode('utf-8'),pageLine):
        return True
    else:
        return False


#Loop through the URLs - Loop A
for url in urls:
    url=url.rstrip('\n')
    outFile('\nOpening ' + url) 
#    response=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
#    html=response.read().decode()
    html=getPage(str(url))
    if html !='':
        outFile('Page read successfully')
    else:
        outFile('Problem reading page')

    outFile(url + ' has ' + str(len(html)) + ' lines')

    #Loop through targetStrings - Loop B. This is only happening on the first pass of loop A.
    for line in targetFile:
        outFile('Beginning \'for line in targetFile:\' loop')
        line=line.rstrip('\n') #take out any \n newline characters at the end
        outFile('Looking for ' + line + ' in ' + url)
        foundCount=0

        # Loop through current HTML file - Loop C
        pageLineNumber=0
        for pageLine in html:
            pageLineNumber+=1
            pageLine=pageLine.encode('utf-8')
            outFile('Looking for ' + str(line) + ' in ' + str(pageLineNumber) + ' ' + str(pageLine))
            if match(line, pageLine):
                foundCount+=1
                outFile('FoundCount is ' + str(foundCount))
        outFile('Searched ' + str(pageLineNumber) + ' lines')

        if foundCount==0:
            outFile('Did not find ' + str(line))
        else:
            s=''
            if foundCount>0:
                s='s'
            outFile('Found ' + line + ' ' + str(foundCount) + ' time' + s)
            foundCount=0
f.close()
urls.close()
targetFile.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in your nested for loops. In `for line in targetFile:` you are reading "targetFile" in each iteration of outer loop. You cannot read a file object more than once as once completely read, read pointer is set to end of file. You either need to create a new file object or use `file_obj.seek(0)` to move the read pointer to start of the file again.
So you can add `targetFile.seek(0)` as the last line for your outer loop after the `for line in targetFile:` loop.

```
for url in urls:
    # outer loop code
    for line in targetFile:
        # inner loop code
    targetFile.seek(0)

f.close()
urls.close()
targetFile.close()
```

Other and better option as suggested by @pvg is to read all the lines in a list

```
targetLines=open('targetStrings.txt','r',encoding=('utf-8')).readlines()
```

and use that list afterwards

```
for line in targetLines:
```

As it will be more efficient than reading the file again and again.

Comment: I like (and upvoted) this because it includes a 'minimally invasive' solution. It is inefficient to keep re-reading the file, though, even if the overhead, assuming caching, will be largely syscalls. I think you should add the other sane option of simply reading the lines into a list to begin with, then it will be a nice, comprehensive answer with a good explanation of the problem with the original code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that my code already had read it into an array but I didn't know I needed to do the readlines() thing. I'm learning Python as I go along so this is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

the problem here is that when you first iterate over the file `targetFile` the read pointer in it is in the end of the file, and when you try to loop again you get nothing out of it because you are already in the end. You can do 2 think to solve this

1. put the read pointer in start with the seek method doing `targetFile.seek(0)` before or after you iterate over it
2. read the whole lines of the file in a variable and iterate over it that.